# Fundamental theorem of Algebra in Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, fake-proofs

*Edit: I know that Euler had a method, which was incomplete, then Gauss proved the FTA. If somebody could show me what Euler did, it would be great. I think that's what I need.*

The Aim is to prove the FTA, but using a incomplete proof.
I'm given a polynomial $P(z)$ with degree $n$.

I'm told to consider $P(re^{i\theta})$ where $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$, fix $r$.

I need to argue that there exist $r,\theta$ such that $P(re^{i\theta})=0$, but this proof is non-complete, why?

**My thoughts:**

I know there is a circle for all $r$. Now this circle takes complex values. And I need to map this circle in complex numbers, apply $P$ to it, and see what values the polynomial takes on. Then I can apply intermediate value theorem to find roots.

I also thought about the existence of such number. Every polynomial has a root (I'm not saying there are exactly $n$ roots) $\Rightarrow$ I can always parametrize my root to find such $r,\theta$

Comment: There are many (complete) proofs given [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to build an incomplete proof rather than prove the theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice text of W. Dunham about [Euler and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Polya/07468342.di020748.02p0019l.pdf), which could be what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I had a read but it got me nowhere. So far I figured that if I take $r=0$ then I get a constant term back, if I take $r$ to be big, then this means that $|z|$ is big, meaning that $a_nz^n$ term will dominate the polynomial. I then look at the circle $re^{i\theta}$ and it should have roots spaced $2\theta /n$ apart.

Comment: If $r$ is small then the first term of the polynomial will dominate that is the $a_1z$ term. I don't know how to connect this with the FTA

Comment: I found a video online which showed how for large $r$, bounds the difference between $f(z)$ and $f(re^{i\theta})$, similarly for small $r$. Thus the $z^n$ term, corresponding to $re^{ni\theta}$ will circle the plane $n$ times, so it has to cross the axis $n$ times. Those are the roots (from my understanding)

Comment: I see, this sounds interesting.